# Firebase OTP Verification Fails on Android 14 with FirebaseAuthException

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, android-14, sms-verification

I'm encountering an issue with SMS verification in our app using Firebase OTP. After sending the OTP, we receive an error, but this issue only appears on devices running Android 14. The app works fine on other Android versions. Below is the error message:

`com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that neither SafetyNet checks nor reCAPTCHA checks succeeded. Please try again, or check the logcat for more details.`

We are currently using these dependencies:
`implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.4.1') implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'`

Our app's build configuration is as follows:
`compileSdk 32 minSdk 21 targetSdk 32`

Has anyone else faced a similar issue on Android 14? Are there any known compatibility issues with Firebase and the latest version of Android? Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this error would be greatly appreciated.

What I've Tried:

1. Verifying Dependency Versions: I ensured that all Firebase and AndroidX dependencies are up to date.
   2.Testing on Different Android Versions: The app works as expected on Android versions other than 14, indicating that the issue might be specific to Android 14.
2. Checking for SDK Compatibility: I reviewed the documentation to ensure that our current SDK versions are compatible with Android 14.
3. Logging and Debugging: I've added extensive logging to trace the flow of the OTP request and to catch any anomalies specifically on Android 14 devices.

What I Expected:
I expected the SMS verification process to work seamlessly on Android 14, just as it does on other Android versions. Specifically, the Firebase OTP should be sent and authenticated without triggering the FirebaseAuthException.

What Actually Happened:
Despite the app functioning correctly on other Android versions, on Android 14, it consistently fails at the OTP verification stage, throwing the FirebaseAuthException error mentioned above. This suggests a possible compatibility issue or a missing configuration specific to Android 14.